# Having a few problems after recently starting Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello I have start learning Java coding on Eclipse recently and have only made a few very simple things.

I am trying to make a basic game where a random number from 1-100 is chosen by the program and you have to try and pick it, with the program telling you whether you are higher or lower. However I've encountered a few problems.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*; 
public class numbergame {

    /**Number guessing game 
     * calculates a random number and has the player guess it
     */

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    int myNumber, guess; 
    System.out.println("What is your guess?");
    Scanner guessScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random myNumber = new Random(); 
    int number = randomNumber.nextInt(100); 
    guess = guessScanner;
    if (guess<myNumber) {
        System.out.println ("The Number is less");
    }
    if (guess>myNumber) {
        System.out.println ("Your guess is more"); 
    }
    else{
        if (guess==myNumber)
            System.out.println ("Your number is correct");
    }
    }
}
```

This is what I have done so far,

The following lines are not working but I am not sure how to fix them:

```
Random myNumber = new Random(); 

int number = randomNumber.nextInt(100); 

guess = guessScanner;

if (guess<myNumber) {
```

Could I please have some advice as of how to fix these? And how to make the program record then umber of guesses?

Comment: `randomNumber.nextInt(100);` should be `myNumber.nextInt(100)`, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 guess = guessScanner
```

to

```
 guess = guessScanner.nextInt();
```

You are willing to take the user input as int. But `guess = guessScanner` from this you are assigning `int to Scanner`. That is wrong.

And also change as

```
Random randomNumber = new Random();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign `Scanner` to an `int`:

```
guess = guessScanner;
```

Instead, you should call the `nextInt()` method on it, to get the integer the user inputed:

```
guess = guessScanner.nextInt();
```